# What is the best approach of developing css in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app, extract-text-plugin

I'm wondering how to conveniently develop css styles in unextracted create-react-app. I've just configured scss from using official readme instructions, but it seems that project has a mess of css and scss files. I want something like extract-text-plugin for react or the other convenient way of building css.

By the way, most of all I like to use less with css modules and extraction built styles to the single css file.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use CSS preprocessor? would you consider just using plain css?

Comment: less is more comfortable for structuring and css modules allows to use same classnames in different components